# Insert sections at the beginning of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to add some sections to `UICollectionView`. `insertSections` at the index zero didn't work for me. So my idea was to `insertSections` at the end and then use `moveSection:toSection:` to move the elements from the end to the beginning. Here I get

> NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: attempt to move section 36, but there are only 36 sections before the update

I can only provide C# code, but you can also post Objective-C/Swift.

```
this.controller.CollectionView.PerformBatchUpdatesAsync (
    delegate() {    
        nint sectionsBefore = this.controller.CurrentNumberOfSections;
        this.controller.CurrentNumberOfSections += 12;
        this.controller.CollectionView.InsertSections(NSIndexSet.FromNSRange(new NSRange(sectionsBefore,12)));
        for(nint i=sectionsBefore; i<=this.controller.CurrentNumberOfSections; i++){
            this.controller.CollectionView.MoveSection(i,0);
        }
    }
);
```

**Edit:**

Here is an output of the variables:

```
sectionsBefore: 36  
CurrentNumberOfSections: 48  
Range: <NSIndexSet: 0x7a77b9b0>[number of indexes: 12 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (36-47)]  
36  
37  
38  
39  
40  
41  
42  
43  
44  
45  
46  
47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 36 sections then then your valid section indexes are 0-35, but  your loop will end up calling `MoveSection(36, 0)`.  You should use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same error. I updated my question with the output from the variables used.

Comment: Are you adding new items to your datasource before you insert the sections into your collection view? Also, what line is it crashing on, the insert or the move?

Comment: It crashes on the line with `performBatchUpdates`. `CurrentNumberOfSections` is returned in `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`. So if I set a new number of sections than the rest is automatically generated. If `numberOfItemsInSection` or `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is called then I calculate my content and return it for the presentation for the user.

Comment: Where are you calling `performBatchUpdates`? If you are doing this inside of a batch update call then it definitely isn't going to work since moving multiple sections to index 0 inside a batch update call is going to throw an exception.  I suspect what you really want to do is call `this.controller.CollectionView.InsertSections(NSIndexSet.FromNSRange(new NSRange(0,12)));` and not do any moves.  If your datasource is correctly updated so that a `cellForItemAtIndexPath` call for section 0-11 will return the cells you are adding then it will give you the effect of adding sections at the beginning

Comment: Now I tried what you said. It did work. I thought I already tested that ... One thing I noticed: It seems that the scrollview scrolls to the new added section. Is there a possiblity to prevent this? I want to add the sections but I don't want to scroll.